# How can I display the remaining key values when a user selects the first key from a JSON object in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I have a simple API that returns a list of countries, their dial code and the country code. I'm trying to display the **dial_code** and and **country_code** when user selects the **country_name** from the select options. I'll later set states for the selected country name, code and dial code. The point is I can directly set states for the other two, but I need to show the country_code and dial_code to the user as well. The part I've commented is not working because it is out of **v-for** scope. How can I resolve this?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="app">
<select>
  <option v-for="country in countries">{{country.country_name }}</option>
</select>
<!-- 
<p>
    Dial Code: {{ country.dial_code }}
</p>
<p>    
    Code: {{ country.country_code }}
</p> 
-->
</div>
```

And here's the JS (I've trimmed the API call response for demo):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    countries:[
       {
        "country_name":"Afghanistan",
        "dial_code": "+93",
        "country_code": "AF"
       },
       {
        "country_name":"Zimbabwe",
        "dial_code": "+263",
        "country_code": "ZW"
       }
    ]
},
  methods: {
 }
});
```

Required result:

[image]

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

Use `v-model` with a variable, for example `selectedCountry` like suggested in other answer. Then bind that to the select and add `value` to the select:

```html
<select v-model="selectedCountry">
  <option
    v-for="(country, index) in countries"
    :value="country"
    :key="index"
  >{{country.country_name }}</option>
</select>
```

Then you have the selected object stored in `selectedCountry` and you can show `selectedCountry.dial_code` and `selectedCountry.country_code` in template.

**[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-flower-g07s6)**

Comment: Thanks a ton! Exactly what I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Define a property for selected country :

```
 data: {
    countries:[
       {
        "country_name":"Afghanistan",
        "dial_code": "+93",
        "country_code": "AF"
       },
       {
        "country_name":"Zimbabwe",
        "dial_code": "+263",
        "country_code": "ZW"
       }
    ],selectedCountry:Object
```

Then in your template use `v-model` to bind `select` to `selectedCountry`

```
<select v-model="selectedCountry">
  <option v-for="country in countries">{{country.country_name }}</option>
</select>
```

Then you can use the `selectedCountry` render the result  as below :

```
<p>
    Dial Code: {{ selectedCountry.dial_code }}
</p>
<p>    
    Code: {{ selectedCountry.country_code }}
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it still doesn't seem to work. I looked through v-model for two way binding, and it should be working I guess but it's not...